# Is issubclass broken for comparing with typing.Generic in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

How do I find out if a given class is a subclass of any `typing.Generic`? Calling `issubclass` does not seem to work as I expected:

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')

class A(typing.Generic[T]):
    pass

class B:
    pass

issubclass(A, typing.Generic)
>>> True

issubclass(B, typing.Generic)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
... <more traceback lines here>
File "<some_path>\env\lib\abc.py", line 225, in __subclasscheck__
    for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

Also, am I missing anything and this is an expected behaviour or is this a bug?

So, is it safe to assume that if `TypeError` is raised, then it is NOT a subclass of `typing.Generic`?

I am using Python 3.5.2.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it should be `issubclass(B, typing.Generic[T])`

Comment: It works, yes, but in this case only, as a generic can have more than one type parameter provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior (as of right now, at least). You can't mix a type as specified in the context of type hinting with a class. You can consider a `type` as being a tag, an indication for a possible type checker. A class is a runtime object with which you interact.

More information can be found in the following [thread on the issue tracker](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/136) for the typing module (specifically, look in [this](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/136#issuecomment-217369506) post).

Just for the record, `typing` is still **provisional**, many bugs and many changes might occur until it is considered stable, they are still tweaking it and no guarantees are in place. As an example, in `Python 3.5.1` your code runs smoothly w/o any `TypeError`s (they were introduced in `3.5.2` from what I gather):

```
issubclass(A, typing.Generic)
Out[28]: True

issubclass(B, typing.Generic)
Out[31]: False
```